# Derivative of matrix expression with norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, least-squares

I am reading http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ and on chapter $4$ Numerical Computation, at page 94, we read:

> Suppose we want to find the value of $\boldsymbol{x}$ that minimizes $$f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{2}||\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}||_2^2$$ We can obtain the gradient $$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{A}^T(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}) = \boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b}$$

So I tried to derive this myself, but didn't quite get there.

**My Try**

$$f(\boldsymbol{x}) = (\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b})^T(\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{b}) = \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{b}$$ then since the second and third term are just scalars, their transpose is the same as the other, thus we can cancel them out. Thus we have $$\nabla_xf(\boldsymbol{x}) = \nabla_x(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{b}) = ?$$

I really can't continue, I have no idea how to solve that..

**My attempt**

From above we have $$f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{b}\right)$$

From one of the answers below we calculate $$f(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon} - \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}- \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} -\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+ 
\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{b}\right)$$

Now we notice that the fist is contained in the second, so we can just obtain their difference as $$f(\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}) - f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}
 + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon} - \boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{b}-\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\right)$$

Now we look at the shapes of the matrices. Suppose $\boldsymbol{A}$ has shape (n,m), then $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ have shape (m,1) and $\boldsymbol{b}$ has shape (n,1). Then the first three terms have shape (1,1), i.e they are scalars. For scalar values, we know that they are equal to their transpose. Also, we replace $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ by $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$. Notice that the transpose of the second term is equal to the first term. Similarly, the transpose of the penultimate term is equal to the last term. Therefore $$f(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}) + f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\epsilon} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$ therefore dividing by $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ we have $$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}$$

Notice that the first term is a vector times a square matrix $\boldsymbol{M} = \boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}$, thus using the property suggested in the comments, we can "transpose it" and the expression is $$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{A}$$

Which is very similar to what I need to obtain, except that the last term is transposed. However, we cannot use the same trick we just used because $\boldsymbol{A}$ doesn't necessarily have to be square!

Comment: "we can cancel them out" ...you sure?

Comment: oh shit the sign is the same!

Comment: @Paul I still have no idea how to solve it though

Comment: Notice that for any square matrix M and vector p, $p^T M = M^T p$ (think row times column in each product). Don't forget the $\frac{1}{2}$ too.

Comment: mmh okay. But how do I differentiate that?

Comment: Does it only work for square matrices?

Comment: If $e=(1, 1,...,1)$ and M is not square then $p^T Me =e^T M^T p$ will do the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I differentiate expressions like yours. Let $y = x+\epsilon$. Then, e.g. $$g(y) = y^TAy = x^TAx + x^TA\epsilon + \epsilon^TAx + \epsilon^TA\epsilon$$. Then $$g(x+\epsilon) - g(x) = x^TA\epsilon + x^TA^T\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).$$ So the gradient is $$x^TA + x^TA^T.$$ The other terms in $f$ can be treated similarly. This approach works because the gradient is related to the linear approximations of a function near the base point $x$.

---

I looked through your work in response to my answer, and you did it exactly right, except for the transposing bit at the end. It is not actually true that for any square matrix $Mx = x^TM^T$ since the results don't even have the same shape! Also, you can't divide by epsilon, since it is a vector. The right way to finish is to go from $f(x+\epsilon) - f(x) = (x^TA^TA -b^TA)\epsilon$ to concluding that $x^TA^TA -b^TA$ is the gradient (since this is the linear function that epsilon is multiplied by). This is actually the transpose of what you are looking for, but that is just because this approach considers the gradient a row vector rather than a column vector, which is no big deal. Just go ahead and transpose it.

Comment: do you know some resources where I could study that? I'm majoring in maths but I've never seen this neither in linear algebra, nor in calculus..

Comment: Also in my case I don't get the desired result

Comment: I learned this in a nonlinear functional analysis course, but I don't remember the textbook, unfortunately. The idea is very generic, though. Given a function $f: X \to Y$, the gradient at $x\inX$ is the best linear approximation, i.e. a linear function $L:X\to Y$ such that $||f(x+h) - f(x) - Lh||/||h|| \to 0$. This is the same as saying that $||f(x+h) - f(x) - Lh|| \to 0$ faster than $||h||$. The technique is to compute $f(x+h) - f(x)$, find the terms which are linear in $h$, and call them the derivative. So it is basically just computing derivatives from the definition.

Comment: I am happy to help work through the details if you post your attempt.

Comment: I added my attempt to the question above! As you can see I get close but not quite there yet.

Comment: @Euler_Salter I edited my answer to explain how to fix your work.

Comment: thank you a lot! Do you think this sort of work should be seen at undergraduate level maths?

Comment: Sure. As you can see, it does not require a deep knowledge of derivatives and is in a sense the most natural thing to do if you understand the derivative idea. My impression that most people learn a list of rules for taking derivatives with matrices but I never remember them and find this way reliable, especially at the graduate level when things become infinite-dimensional...